# For Each loop over an Array in MapBasic?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic, vb

.NET C# developer here. Trying to figure out MapBasic with the IDE for the first time. It's shall we say...a different experience to C# in Visual studio.

I have a `ButtonPad` with a button that calls a stored proc in the SQL server db which performs an insert on one selected polygon in my BidBlock layer:

```
' User Hit Bid Block
print cmd_INFO_MENUITEM
if getSelectionInfo(SelCount, SelTableName) then
    if SelCount = 1 then
        'Have one Contract selected
        if selTableName = vwBidBlocks then
            i_blockId = selection.block_id
            if i_blockId = 0 then
                run menu command 304
                note "Please re-select your Bid Block."
        '       set handler WinChangedHandler on
                exit sub
            end if
            'call notyet()
            call BidBlock(i_blockID)
        else
            dialog error handling blah blah
```

I'm now trying to implement this function to perform on a selection of > 1 polygons in the layer. I want to therefore make an dynamic array of items using `reDim(selection)`?

& itterate over the ID's of each selected item in the array calling my `BidBlock(i_blockId)` function. In C# I would use a `for each` loop here which implements the `IEnumberable` interface. Is there any way of doing this in MapBasic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no For Each in MapBasic unfortunately. A selection in MapInfo is effectively a table, so what you want to do is loop through the Selection table. The best way to do that is by using `Do...Loop` and `Fetch`. Something like this should work:

```
Dim alBlockID as Alias
Dim selectionName, selTableName as String
Dim selCount, i_blockId as Integer

selectionName = SelectionInfo(SEL_INFO_SELNAME)
selTableName = SelectionInfo(SEL_INFO_TABLENAME)
selCount = SelectionInfo(SEL_INFO_NROWS)

alBlockID = selTableName & ".block_id"

If selCount > 1 and selTableName = vwBidBlocks then
    Fetch first from selectionName    '// fetch the first record
    Do While Not EOT(selectionName)    '// do while not at the end of the selection table
        i_blockId = alBlockID
        If i_blockId = 0 then
            Run Menu Command 304
            Note "Please re-select your Bid Block."
            '       set handler WinChangedHandler on
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'call notyet()
        Call BidBlock(i_blockID)

        Fetch next from selectionName    '// fetch the next record
    Loop
End If
```

Comment: Great thank you, got the code to invoke my BidBlock(i_blockID) method. This calls the stored proc & executes on my first selected record however the selection is then cleared therefore leaving me with no next record in the selected table. Is there a way to keep the selection alive?